# Why is communication between a Python program and Arduino not producing the expected result?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, python

I have written some Arduino code (with help from the post *[Serial Input Basics](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=396450.0)*). On serial I send some data and, based on certain values sent, certain LEDs will be lit. Here is the Arduino code:

```
const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];
char tempChars[numChars];        // Temporary array for use when parsing

// Variables to hold the parsed data
//char messageFromPC[numChars] = {0};
int cmd = 0;
int pitch = 0;
int velocity = 0;
int integerFromPC = 0;
int int2FromPC = 0;
boolean newData = false;

void setup() {

    // Put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);//set baud rate

    //Configure pins 2:5 as OUTPUT
    pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    recvWithStartEndMarkers();
    if (newData == true) {
        strcpy(tempChars, receivedChars);
        // This temporary copy is necessary to protect the original data
        // because strtok() used in parseData() replaces the commas with \0.

        parseData();
        showParsedData();
        if(cmd==144 && velocity!=0){
            switch(pitch){
                case 30:
                    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
                    break;

                case 31:
                     digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
                     break;

                case 32:
                    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
                    break;

                case 33:
                    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(cmd==144 && velocity==0){
            switch(pitch){

                case 30:
                    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
                    break;

                case 31:
                    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
                    break;

                case 32:
                    digitalWrite(4, LOW);
                    break;

                case 33:
                    digitalWrite(5, LOW);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        newData = false;
    }
}

void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {

    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;

    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();

        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= numChars) {
                    ndx = numChars - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // Terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                newData = true;
            }
        }

        else if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;
        }
    }
}

void parseData() {      // Split the data into its parts

    char * strtokIndx;  // This is used by strtok() as an index

    strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars, " "); // Get the first part - the string
    //strcpy(messageFromPC, strtokIndx); // Copy it to messageFromPC
    cmd = atoi(strtokIndx);

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, " ");      // This continues where the previous call left off
    //integerFromPC = atoi(strtokIndx);  // Convert this part to an integer
    pitch = atoi(strtokIndx);

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, " ");
    velocity = atoi(strtokIndx);         // Convert this part to a float
}

void showParsedData() {
    Serial.print("Comm ");
    Serial.println(cmd);
    Serial.print("Ptch ");
    Serial.println(pitch);
    Serial.print("Velo ");
    Serial.println(velocity);
    Serial.println("\n");
}
```

Now this works perfectly with sending data from the Arduino's serial monitor, so for example if I type the following on serial monitor:

```
<144 30 45>
```

Then the LED I expect to get lit does, and I can turn it off by:

```
<144 30 0>
```

Now, I want to send this data from a Python (2.7) program which I am reproducing here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1421', 9600)
noteOn = 144
veloMid = 75
veloSilent = 0
def sendData(cmd, pitch, velocity):
    global ser
    cmd = bytes(cmd)
    pitch = bytes(pitch)
    velocity = bytes(velocity)
    ser.write("<")
    ser.write(cmd)
    ser.write(pitch)
    ser.write(velocity)
    ser.write(">")

while 1:
    notes = range(30, 34)
    for note in notes:
        sendData(noteOn, note, veloMid)
        time.sleep(2)
        sendData(noteOn, note, veloSilent)
```

The idea was to do the same thing I was doing manually in serial monitor, except using a Python script. But this produces no result. I see the RX and TX pins on the Arduino toggling, so it looks like the program is indeed communicating with the Arduino. In the Python IDE I wrote a few lines as follows to read the data from Arduino:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1421', 9600, timeout=5)
while True:
    data_raw = ser.read()
    print data_raw
```

With above code I receive the following characters in the Python IDE:

```
C
o
m
m


P
t
c
h


V
e
l
o
```

I have a feeling there is some mismatch between the data types of the data I am sending between the Python script and the Arduino, but I am not sure exactly what this mismatch might be.

- Why am I not seeing the values of cmd, pitch and veocity being printed out from the serial.read() although the other strings "Comm   Ptch   Velo" are printed?
- What dataype is serial.write passing on that might than be causing mismatch with my Arduino code?

Comment: This is how you format code: Use the code formatting markdown (four leading spaces). For help see [Markdown help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You should be able to do this by selecting the code and pressing `Ctrl+K` to have your browser do this for you. It was hard work changing your tags (from I don't know where) into what works here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test with the serial monitor you are putting spaces between each number. Using my logic analyzer I got this being sent from your Python code to the Arduino:

[image: Logic analyzer image]

No spaces, right? So the Arduino is receiving:

```
<1443175>
```

And since you are using a space as a numeric delimiter your decoding isn't working.

---

Something like this is probably warranted:

```python
    ser.write("<")
    ser.write(cmd)
    ser.write(" ")
    ser.write(pitch)
    ser.write(" ")
    ser.write(velocity)
    ser.write(">")
```

Comment: Nick....You are a genius!!! The spaces were exactly the problem. I completely forgot the spaces when I switched to the python code. After correctly formatting my output string things work as I want. Many thanks for your suggestion. I also apologize for the formatting issue. I will keep your suggested link handy next time I submit a question.